# JS Returned a string (HTML type), would it be possible to have a trigger on selected html tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a query in JS and returned string in html type, see below

```html
<table>
  <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
          <select id="one" onchange="someFunctionHere()">
            <option value="value1">Value 1</option>            
            <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
          </select>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
          <select id="two" onchange="someFunctionHere()">
            <option value="value1">Value 1</option>            
            <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
          </select>
      </td>
  </tr>
  .
  .
  
</table>
```

I have an AJAX call to request data from a server, the data returned is the markup I supplied above. As part of the callback from the AJAX request, I want to parse the request and search for an onchange event in the `<select>` element. If a match is found, I want to invoke the function named in the onchange event.

Comment: Please show us all relevant code. That includes the JS you're talking about. Your explanation of what exactly you want isn't very clear. Showing the code might clear things up.

Comment: I second the sentiment of @icecub.  It's not clear what you're looking for.  This is how I interpret your request:  1) You want to use AJAX to request data from a server;  2)  The data returned is the markup you supplied above;  3)  As part of the callback from the AJAX request, you want to parse the request and search for an `onchange` event in the `<select>` element; 4)  If a match is found, you want to invoke the function named in the `onchange` event; 5)  Either way you want to discard the markup returned from your AJAX request.  Is this an accurate picture of what you're after?

Comment: you nailed it @SimianAngel, that's the exact explanation.

Comment: Sweet!  You might consider editing your question to make your intentions more clear to those who would help out. :)  Okay, so parsing the result of your AJAX request as a string, then searching for a function call as referenced in an `onchange` event.  Is it reasonable to expect that the function already exists on the page?  What is the expected behavior if the function isn't an anonymous function, and does _not_ exist on the page?

Comment: The function is already exist in other file (JS File). 

In my old version, the returned string was displayed and all I have to do is to choose any of the value in "select" tag. The "select" tag has a behavior, like "onchange", so the function is called. That "onchage" function request data in the server and output it one-by-one until its done. 

Now, all I need is to implement a "single click" operation. That's why I raise this question.

Comment: You can do like this : use some regex /string function to get js code for onchange then use `eval()` to run it

Comment: @Novice, thanks to your suggestion and I will extra time to study that thing.

Comment: @SimianAngel, thank you for explaining well my problem :)